# issues while installing engine.io node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm, engine.io

I am trying to install `engine.io`
(https://www.npmjs.com/package/engine.io)

I am getting the following **error**:

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install engine.io

ws@0.5.0 install C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws
(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


C:\Windows\system32\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws>node "C:\Program File
s (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bi
n\node-gyp.js" rebuild
engine.io@1.5.1 node_modules\engine.io
├── base64id@0.1.0
├── debug@1.0.3 (ms@0.6.2)
├── engine.io-parser@1.2.1 (blob@0.0.2, arraybuffer.slice@0.0.6, after@0.8.1, ba
se64-arraybuffer@0.1.2, utf8@2.0.0, has-binary@0.1.5)
└── ws@0.5.0 (options@0.0.6, ultron@1.0.1, nan@1.4.3)
```

After this I try to execute this js script

```
var engine = require('engine.io');
var server = engine.listen(80);

server.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.send('utf 8 string');
  socket.send(new Buffer([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // binary data
});
```

I get this **error**

> C:\Windows\system32>node "c:\users\user\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projec ts\nodes\WebApplication1\NodeFiles\engineTest.js"
>   module.js:338
>       throw err;
>             ^
>       Error: Cannot find module 'engine.io'
>           at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
>           at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
>           at require (module.js:384:17)
>           at Object. (c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Proje
>       cts\node\WebApplication1\NodeFiles\engineTest.js:1:76)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>           at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Actually I think I am not doing something right. Let me explain

First of all i think the installation of `engine.io` is correct as all of you are suggesting.

Now when I try running the command `"var engine = require('engine.io');"` from the node console, it works perfectly and the engine variable is instantiated with the data.

When I check engine it shows me.

```
C:\Users\Ankur>node
> var engine = require('engine.io');
undefined
> engine
{ [Function]
  protocol: 1,
  Server:
   { [Function: Server]
     errors:
      { UNKNOWN_TRANSPORT: 0,
        UNKNOWN_SID: 1,
        BAD_HANDSHAKE_METHOD: 2,
        BAD_REQUEST: 3 },
     errorMessages:
      { '0': 'Transport unknown',
        '1': 'Session ID unknown',
        '2': 'Bad handshake method',
        '3': 'Bad request' } },
  Socket: [Function: Socket],
  Transport: [Function: Transport],
  transports:
   { polling: { [Function: polling] upgradesTo: [Object] },
     websocket: [Function: WebSocket] },
  parser:
   { protocol: 3,
     packets:
      { open: 0,
        close: 1,
        ping: 2,
        pong: 3,
        message: 4,
        upgrade: 5,
        noop: 6 },
     encodePacket: [Function],
     encodeBase64Packet: [Function],
     decodePacket: [Function],
     decodeBase64Packet: [Function],
     encodePayload: [Function],
     decodePayload: [Function],
     encodePayloadAsBinary: [Function],
     decodePayloadAsBinary: [Function] },
  listen: [Function: listen],
  attach: [Function: attach] }
>
```

But when I write that line in a JS file and then try and run it with the node command it breaks.**Error**

```
C:\Users\Ankur>node "e:\engine.js"
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'engine.io'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\engine.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)

C:\Users\Ankur>
```

I think I am doing something silly.

Could someone please help me out?

Comment: What is the error? seems to me that it was installed correctly

Comment: tried the global installation. still it says :Error: Cannot find module 'engine.io'
when i run my script

Comment: On windows, it's often a missing environment variable that causes globally installed modules to not be found.

Comment: Could you please have a look now, I have updated the question. It seems that the issue is something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed the `engine.io` module under the directory `C:\Windows\system32`. This means that you have a `node_modules` folder in `systems32`, not in your project folder. This is not what you want.

I would recommend you start from scratch:

Open the cmd and do the following commands

1. Create a folder for your project:

   - `mkdir testproject`
2. Navigate into the text projects folder:

   - `cd testproject`
3. Install the modules you require, i.e. `engine.io`:

   - `npm install engine.io`
4. Now you should have a folder named `node_modules` in your project folder
5. Create the file `app.js` in the project folder with your content.
6. Run `app.js`

   - `node app.js`

Your app should now work.

Comment: so i think what it sums up as is  that if i would have added the node modules folder in the PATH variable in the environment variables .. i wouldnt have to install  it separately in the folder where my project is located??

Comment: You can install a module globally like this: `npm install -g <modulename>`. More on modules [here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#loading_from_node_modules_Folders).

Comment: i installed it as a global thing with -g as you suggested and copied my script in a new folder . now i tried to run that from the new folder as e:\newfolder> node script.js -> it again throws the error that cannot find module engine.io